# Why is Ruby so much slower than Java?

Tags: java, ruby

I was working on the Project Euler problems, when I stumbled on [this problem](https://projecteuler.net/problem=14). I wrote a program that solves it correctly in Ruby on Rails (new to the language):

```
class Collatz
 def search
    counter = 0
    storage = 0
    amount = 0
    (1..1000000).each do |i| i += 1
      temp = i
      while temp != 1
        temp = temp & 1 == 1 ? 3 * temp + 1 : temp >> 1
        counter += 1
      end
      if counter > amount
        amount = counter
        storage = i
      end
      counter = 0
    end
    puts storage
  end
end

start = Time.now
collatz = Collatz.new
collatz.search
ending = Time.now
puts "Time: #{ending - start}"
```

I realized that it took a very long time, 15.185317 seconds to be exact. 
When I try Java, however, the time is much shorter:

```
public class Euler{

    private static void problem() {
        long a;
        int j;
        int max = 0;
        int maxnr = 0;
        for(int i = 1; i < 1000000; i++) {
            a = i;
            j = 1;
            while( a != 1 ) {
                a = ((a & 1) == 1) ? (3 * a + 1) : (a >> 1);
                j++;
            }
            if(j > max) {
                max = j;
                maxnr = i;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(maxnr);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long ct = System.currentTimeMillis();
        problem();
        long nt = System.currentTimeMillis() - ct;
        System.out.println(nt);
}
```

In the end this program took 769 milliseconds. I am using RubyMine for Ruby and Intellij IDEA for Java. I can't seem to figure out why it takes so long, and I'm not sure if it is normal or not. The task doesn't seem too difficult, since I'm just looping.

Comment: I don't know much about ruby execution but for Java, the JVM has JIT (Just In Time) which improves the performance of the code being executed, and improves it more when the code is executed several times.

Comment: You can't compare a single aspect of a language by (poorly) measuring it. Comparing the benchmarks of two methods in the same program (and language) is already hard enough to do right.

Comment: Which implementations of Ruby and Java did you use? There are *enormous* performance differences between different implementations of Java and Ruby. Did you account for JIT warmup? (It doesn't look like it from your benchmark code.) Did you make sure that your results are statistically sound and significant? Note that there's a reason why benchmarks are written by professional benchmark writers: because its *incredibly* hard to write a good benchmark, and at least equally hard to properly interpret its results.

Comment: Try using JRuby, which can be a faster way to run Ruby.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your solution to this problem is quite poor. It involves doing an enormous amount of duplicate work. Apparantly, the JVM is a lot better at optimizing this redundant work than Ruby.

However, if you would write a proper solution, which explicitly uses previous work you will find that it won't matter if you run it on Ruby or Java. You can do this by using an array or a map to store previous results. This technique is also known as dynamic programming.

Comment: One of the things the JVM is good at is optimising redundant work.